# Proxy request through Apache host to docker container

Tags: apache, docker, geoserver, proxypass

I have an Ubuntu server host running an Apache web server. Running on this host is a docker container serving Geoserver (via Tomcat) (built from this [image](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver)) with a port configuration as such: 0.0.0.0:32770->8080/tcp

I can access Geoserver just fine using http://my.domain:32770/geoserver
I have a redirect configured in Apache on the host to serve all requests over HTTPS (see code snippet below), which does not play nicely with the port in requests like this(ie. https://my.domain:32770/geoserver)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # sending http requests to https
        ServerName data.nrri.umn.edu
        Redirect permanent / https://data.nrri.umn.edu/
</VirtualHost>
```

My attempt at a workaround for this is to use the `ProxyPass` directive in an Apache config file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /my-geoserver http://127.0.0.1:32770/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /my-geoserver http://127.0.0.1:32770/geoserver
```

When I use the URL that I would expect would get me to the Geoserver home page like the one above does (ie. http://my.domain/my-geoserver) I am redirected to
https://my.domain/geoserver/index.html and presented with 404 Not Found.
I should also note that both http://my.domain:32770/geoserver and http://my.domain:32770/geoserver/index.html resolve to http://my.domain:32770/geoserver/web/

What am I doing wrong here?

*Edit*
Output from `curl -L -v -o /dev/null data.nrri.umn.edu/nra-geoserver`

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 131.212.123.7...
* Connected to data.nrri.umn.edu (131.212.123.7) port 80 (#0)
> GET /nra-geoserver HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: data.nrri.umn.edu
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 15:28:35 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Location: /geoserver/index.html
< Content-Length: 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DFECFFB91353A34C407488EAAF70A2B4; Path=/geoserver; HttpOnly
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host data.nrri.umn.edu left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'HTTP://data.nrri.umn.edu/geoserver/index.html'
* Found bundle for host data.nrri.umn.edu: 0x95b8c0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host data.nrri.umn.edu
* Connected to data.nrri.umn.edu (131.212.123.7) port 80 (#0)
> GET /geoserver/index.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: data.nrri.umn.edu
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 15:28:35 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Location: https://data.nrri.umn.edu/geoserver/index.html
< Content-Length: 336
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
* Ignoring the response-body
{ [data not shown]
100   336  100   336    0     0  38536      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 38536
* Connection #0 to host data.nrri.umn.edu left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://data.nrri.umn.edu/geoserver/index.html'
* Found bundle for host data.nrri.umn.edu: 0x95b8c0
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 131.212.123.7...
* Connected to data.nrri.umn.edu (131.212.123.7) port 443 (#1)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [data not shown]
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=MN; L=Minneapolis; O=University of Minnesota; OU=Natural Resources Research Institute; CN=data.nrri.umn.edu
*        start date: 2017-04-18 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2020-04-17 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: data.nrri.umn.edu matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=MI; L=Ann Arbor; O=Internet2; OU=InCommon; CN=InCommon RSA Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /geoserver/index.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: data.nrri.umn.edu
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 15:28:35 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 301
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
{ [data not shown]
100   301  100   301    0     0   4404      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4404
* Connection #1 to host data.nrri.umn.edu left intact
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the redirect is configured and provide the relevant configuration for it and Tomcat if you have done any additonal?

Comment: I added my Apache redirect configuration that I have on my host. As far Tomcat running in the container, I haven't done a thing there, nor am I very familiar with configuring Tomcat; I accepted what was done in the Dockerfile as is.

Comment: Can you try and do `curl -L -v -o /dev/null  http://my.domain/my-geoserver` and pos the output so we can see the redirect headers? It almost sounds like there are two redirects happening here. I'm confused how `http://my.domain/my-geoserver` is redirecting to `https://my.domain/geoserver/index.html`.

Comment: Okay. Just updated question with that output.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are two redirects happening. I am not sure of a good way to solve the first one (and it is possible the solution solves it as well as the second one). But the second one, you should be able to add a trailing `/` to the paths. The resulting proxy directives would be:

```
ProxyPass /my-geoserver/ http://127.0.0.1:32770/geoserver/
ProxyPassReverse /my-geoserver/ http://127.0.0.1:32770/geoserver/
```

Give this a try first at http://data.nrri.umn.edu/geoserver/index.html and then with http://data.nrri.umn.edu/nra-geoserver and see where it fails next. If the former works but the latter fails, we'll probably need to edit some Tomcat configuration as well (to enable the remote IP valve https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html).

Comment: I implemented the changes you listed above, but the same thing occurs, http://data.nrri.umn.edu/nra-geoserver resolves to http://data.nrri.umn.edu/geoserver/index.html and I get a 404 Not Found page

Comment: It looks like it's trying to get to /geoserver/index.html on data.nrri.umn.edu, but there's nothing there. Instead geoserver is at data.nrri.umn.edu:32770 (ie. data.nrri.umn.edu:32770/geoserver)